# Why is Kaspersky avp.exe making tons of HTTP requests?

Tags: anti-virus

I'm working in Visual Studio and debugging an Azure cloud project with Fiddler running so I can debug HTTP requests, and I noticed gobs and gobs of HTTP requests being generated by `avp.exe`.  That's Kaspersky's client - and the requests were against my cloud storage account being used by the project in Visual Studio.

Why in the world is Kaspersky making all those requests?

Answer (score 1):

What types of requests are they? Some anti-virus projects inject themselves into your network stack and take over ALL network requests (so they can strip content out of the responses if they think it's malicious).

So, for instance, if you have these products installed, you will find all of your requests from IE for HTML/Images/CSS/etc start coming from the anti-virus proxy's process.

Answer (score 1):

LANDesk Antivirus (Kaspersky) has an option to act as a proxy. When that's on, I've had trouble with Google Hangouts with screen sharing. You can turn it off under Settings - Advanced Settings - Proxy Server Settings - uncheck Use Proxy Server.

Keep in mind that this setting may revert if you're on a LAN where your network administrators control these settings.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What Version of Kaspersky are you using? Kaspersky used to have a history of doing this in the past due to a bug. Are this requested occurring at 5 minute intervals?

Comment: I have 6.0.4.1424, and the request intervals are in the millisecond range (i didn't measure the intervals, but it was like 18k requests over a couple of minutes).  A _lot_.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to fix.

Add following string in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com
```

(this would route all that traffic to your host)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me..

Each browser has a different host request... so add these entries below to your host file: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Chrome, FireFox, IE;

```
127.0.0.1 gc.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com
127.0.0.1 ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com
127.0.0.1 ie.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com
```